# What are the `external node` and nameless node in `opt`-generated dot callgraphs?

Tags: llvm, call-graph

When I generate a dot callgraph with `opt -analyze -dot-callgraph`, there are generated two "special" nodes, one with the name/label `external node` and one with no label assigned.

What do these represent?

Edit: In this idiotic example:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

class Animal
{
public:
    virtual void speak() = 0;
};

class Dog : public Animal
{
public:
    void speak() override { printf("Woof!\n"); }
};

class Cat : public Animal
{
public:
    void speak() override { printf("Meow!\n"); }
};

class Programmer : public Animal
{
public:
    void speak() override { printf("Hello, world!\n"); }
};


int main()
{
    Animal *dog = new Dog;
    Animal *cat = new Cat;
    Animal *guy = new Programmer;

    dog->speak();
    cat->speak();
    guy->speak();

    delete dog;
    delete cat;
    delete guy;
}
```

When generating a callgraph, we have the situation that the `external node` calls all the `speak` implementations. Why is that so? Only `main` calls them; how can anything from the outside call them?

We also see that `main` calls the "nameless" node. What does this mean?

Even more confusingly, if we replace the pure virutal `speak` in `Animal` with say:

```cpp
virtual void speak() { printf("Generic animal sound!\n"); }
```

Then the callgraph no longer shows `main` calling any of the `speak` functions, yet it obviously does call them.

Comment: At the LLVM level, `main` does not call `speak`. It calls `dog->vtable[0]()`. So I assume the nameless node is what you get as the call target when you invoke a function through a function pointer. I don't know what the external node represents here or why not making `Animal::speak` purely virtual makes a difference though. I would not expect the call graph to show a call to a `speak` function in either version.